# PHP 8 setup on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: php, linux, bash, terminal

I'm new to Ubuntu, having used Windows for many years, but switched to Ubuntu permanently, and while I have experience with the terminal, I'm not entirely familiar with commands in Linux. I don't have enough experience to solve the problems that eventually come my way and I don't want to install or modify something the wrong way.

Based on several "Dockerfile" files I have managed to find everything necessary to install the most used dependencies in PHP. However, some commands don't work correctly, and in some cases I get some permission errors that I can't understand.

```bash
sudo apt update \
    && sudo apt install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev \
    && sudo mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && sudo chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && sudo echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && sudo echo "keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && sudo gpg --recv-key 0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c \
    && sudo gpg --export 0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c > /usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg \
    && sudo echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && sudo apt update \
    && sudo apt install -y php8.2-cli php8.2-dev \
       php8.2-pgsql php8.2-sqlite3 php8.2-gd \
       php8.2-curl \
       php8.2-imap php8.2-mysql php8.2-mbstring \
       php8.2-xml php8.2-zip php8.2-bcmath php8.2-soap \
       php8.2-intl php8.2-readline \
       php8.2-ldap \
       php8.2-msgpack php8.2-igbinary php8.2-redis php8.2-swoole \
       php8.2-memcached php8.2-pcov php8.2-xdebug \
    && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sLS https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - \
    && sudo apt install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarn.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarn.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && curl -sS https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/pgdg.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/pgdg.gpg] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && sudo apt update \
    && sudo apt install -y yarn \
    && sudo apt install -y mysql-client \
    && sudo apt install -y postgresql-client-14 \
    && sudo apt -y autoremove \
    && sudo apt clean \
    && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*;
```

These are the commands I'm using, but I'd like to simplify them so I can create a bash file that allows me to install everything I need at any time, on any machine.

I know it doesn't seem practical with so many tools and ways to achieve it, but my intention is to experiment and see what solution you can suggest to enrich my knowledge. I believe that with practice it is the most efficient way to learn.

Permissions errors occur when running the command `sudo echo "keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf`, I couldn't figure this out because it is running with "sudo" and it shouldn't give me a permissions error.

I would really appreciate if the community could help me.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the `sudo echo "something" >> test.txt` and then you can check the owner and permissions with `ls -al`. Then you can see the test.txt created with your own user and don't with root.

I found this site with tips:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/sudo-append-data-text-to-file-on-linux-unix-macos/
I suggest checking the second method with shell tips instead of the `tee`. But if you has tee in your environment, sure you can use it.

I hope it helps.